# extracting specific position of character details from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have database like the image and i want show to t1  details whose name is an 'e' in second position and 'x' in the last position , can any one provide me help how to to achieve this

The table looks like this

```
T1        T2    T3
vexes      1    2
becw      12    21
extrst    10    10
vin       15    10
new       35    14
det       10    12
het       15    10
cat       53    52
fexx      10    15
fat       12    15
fatsrot   10    15
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Answer (score 5):

You can write your query like following.

```
select * from yourtable
where t1 like '_e%x'
```

**Note**:

**_**  Represents a single character

**%**  Represents zero or more characters

Comment: thank you for your feed back, and like want to extract specific data where 'e' is in second position and 'x' is in last position.

Comment: I am not getting your comment, can you explain it bit more.

Comment: according to your query i am getting results of 'fexx' column from my table but i need also second position of of 'e' where ever it exists like i have to extract ('vexes', 'becw','new','det', 'het' ) also along with 'fexx'. but the solution you have provided which is also help me to learn new thing.

Comment: In that case change the where as t1 like ‘_e%’

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve it by using `SUBSTRING` and `RIGHT` in following:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE SUBSTRING(t1, 2, 1) = 'e' --2nd character
      AND RIGHT(t1, 1) = 'x' --last character
```